# Load images from device gallery and display in the listview

Tags: android

Actually i am creating an application in which i want to load images from device gallery and display it into the `ListView`.

So how that can be done. please help me to solve this out, if possible with suitable examples

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Follow this article and override your getView() in your listadapter class as an ImageView containing the image you want to display from the internal array.

http://www.vogella.com/articles/AndroidListView/article.html